# Algorithm for inserting into sorted subset

Tags: algorithms, sorting

`A` is a sorted list. `B` is a sorted list, and a subset of `A`.

If an element is inserted into `A` at index `i` what's the most efficient way to determine the correct index `i'` for it's position in `B`?

Given the fact that both lists are sorted, and that we know `B` is subset of `A` I would think we should be able to devise quite an efficient algorithm, but I'm not happy with what I've come up with so far.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the being a subset is of little value if you have no guarantee that B is a congruent part of A; in other words that the distances between common elements are equal. Doing a binary search on both seems plenty efficient to me with the additional advantage of simplicity.

Comment: I would recommend giving us some context for the exact problem your trying to solve as opposed to only the abstracted form.  This is most definitely one of those problems that have numerous ways it could be approached so having more specific details will likely yield better answers.